# Disable \resetcounteronoverlays for single frames

Tags: beamer, numbering, overlays, gb4e

I use the command `\resetcounteroverlays{exx}` in the preamble of my beamer presentation in order to avoid example numbers from changing within a frame. (I am using the `gb4e`-package for numbered example sentences.) However I would like to undo this (i.e. have the example numbers increase) for a single frame.

How can I do this, preferably without specifying each example number by hand?

Here is an mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\resetcounteronoverlays{exx} % I do not want to delete this globally, just for the MWE-frame

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> \textbf{Point 1} \only<1-2>{(Temporary Info)}
            \only<2>{
            \begin{exe}
                \ex \begin{xlist}
                        \ex {This should be 1a}
                        \ex {This should be 1b}
                    \end{xlist}
                \ex \begin{xlist} 
                        \ex {This should be 2a}
                        \ex {This should be 2b}
                    \end{xlist}
            \end{exe}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<3-> \textbf{Point 2} \only<3-4>{(Temporary Info)}
                    \only<4>{
                    \begin{exe}
                        \ex \begin{xlist}
                            \ex {This should be 3a}
                            \ex {This should be 3b}
                        \end{xlist}
                        \ex \begin{xlist} 
                            \ex {This should be 4a}
                            \ex {This should be 4b}
                        \end{xlist}
                    \end{exe} }
            \end{itemize}
        \item<5-> \textbf{Point 3} \only<5-7>{(Temporary Info)}
            \only<6>{
            \begin{exe}
                \ex \begin{xlist}
                    \ex[ ] {This should be 5a}
                    \ex[ ] {This should be 5b}
                    \ex[*] {This should be 5c}
                    \ex[*] {This should be 5d}
                \end{xlist}
            \end{exe}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<7-> \textbf{Point 4}
            \end{itemize}
        \item<8-> \textbf{Point 5}
            \only<9,10>{
            \begin{exe}
                \ex \begin{xlist}
                        \ex {This should be 6a}
                        \ex This should be 6b
                        \ex This should be 6c
                    \end{xlist}
                \ex \begin{xlist}
                        \ex {This should be 7a}
                        \ex This should be 7b
                    \end{xlist}
            \end{exe}}
            \only<10>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Elaboration on Point 5
            \end{itemize}}
        \item<11-> \textbf{Point 6}
            \only<12>{
            \begin{exe}
                \ex \begin{xlist}
                        \ex {This should be 8a}
                        \ex {This should be 8b}
                    \end{xlist}
            \end{exe}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<13-14> Elaboration on Point 6:
                    \begin{exe}
                        \ex {This should be 9a}
                        \ex {This should be 9b}
                    \end{exe}
                \item<14>[$\rightarrow$] Remarks on Point 6.
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    \only<15>{} % I need this in order to have a concluding final slide with all subpoints folded in. (At least I think I do.)

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This should produce a single frame with 15 slides.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the `gb4e` package you could achieve a similar numbering scheme by resuming the counter of the second layer enumeration.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\newcounter{myenumi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \setcounter{myenumi}{0}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> \textbf{Point 1} \only<1-2>{(Temporary Info)}
      \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
          \setcounter{enumi}{\value{myenumi}}
          \item \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                  \item This should be 1a
                  \item This should be 1b
                \end{enumerate}
          \item \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                  \item This should be 2a
                  \item This should be 2b
                \end{enumerate}
          \setcounter{myenumi}{\value{enumi}}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{onlyenv}
    \item<3-> \textbf{Point 2} \only<3-4>{(Temporary Info)}
      \begin{onlyenv}<4>
        \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
          \setcounter{enumi}{\value{myenumi}}
          \item \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                  \item This should be 3a
                  \item This should be 3b
                \end{enumerate}
          \item \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                  \item This should be 4a
                  \item This should be 4b
                \end{enumerate}
          \setcounter{myenumi}{\value{enumi}}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{onlyenv}  
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to keep the command globally and only **disable** it locally. Your suggestion does the opposite.

Comment: @Max But then the item "This should be 1a" will be 3a, is this correct?

Comment: Ideally the example numbers would be those in the example text. Right now I'd be happy with something that just disables the reset-command for a single frame.

Comment: @Max ??? but why do you want to disable the overlayreset if the numbers are correct with it?

Comment: The Numbers _aren't_ correct with it, it just keeps repeating 1 and 2.